# Scroll listener on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, listener, document-body

I would like to ask about scroll listener. I want to add scroll listener on body but it seems doesnt work.

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
  console.log('SCROLL BODY');
});
```

I create basic example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqkkug4e/), can someone explain me why it doesn't to work?
Sorry for nubies question...

Answer (score 10):

Try with:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log('SCROLL BODY');
});
```

This should be supported by all browsers.

Comment: I know I can on window, but I want to add scroll listener to html tag.

Comment: and what different effect do you expect?

Comment: I am trying add scroll listener in the html tag level, not to js object like window, but I think I need to change my approach.

Answer (score 9):

Because the body isn't scrolling, the `window` is.

In [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertmaxrees/g26g7yph/1/), you'll see that the event listener bound to the parent `container` is what's firing, because that element is the one that's actually scrolling.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <p id="content">some text</p>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
#container {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

And the relevant JS looks like this:

```
$('#container').on('scroll', function() {
    console.log('#container');
});

$('#content').on('scroll', function() {
    console.log('#content');
});
```

Comment: So your saying to have scroll on body I would need to set height explicity in css, otherwise the body is constatly expanded and scroll is never there?

Comment: Correct - the body doesn't scroll in your case, so a listener bound to it won't work.  Bind a listener to the window and you're fine.

Comment: I know I can bound listener to window, but I want to add scroll listner to html tag, so in my case windows is not an options, at least if I not gonna change my approach

Comment: Scrolling on body is an unusual thing to do.  I would change your approach if possible to reduce future headaches.  Otherwise, you'll need to add CSS to your body to give you the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Even if the window is scrolling instead of the body, why does << document.body.onscroll = f >> work while << document.body.addEventListener("scroll", f) >> doesn't?

Answer (score 8):

All the answers above expect jQuery being the framework of use. A framework agnostic / plain JS implementation could look like this

ES 5:

```js
// ES 5 :
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onscroll = function() {
    console.log("scrolling");
};
```

ES 6 (and above) :

```js
// ES 6 (and above)
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onscroll = () => {
    console.log("scrolling");
};
```

Comment: Or you could just refer to document.body - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body

Answer (score 3):

### The Pure JS Solution

Everything is very simple: just use `addEventListener` for scrolling event.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', function( event ) {
    console.log(';{};');
} );
```

And make `body` scrollable with CSS:

```css
:root {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

I do not know why simple handler assignment doesn't work. If you know why — please, tell me.

```
document.body.onscroll = function( event ) {
    console.log('You will never see this message.');
};
```

---

Also you could do this:

```
document.body.onwheel = function( e ) {
    ...
};
```

This event will be triggered only when you using a wheel (for me that wasn't obvious, actually), so if you will scroll your page with a scrollbar it will not trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply using
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onscroll2

```
 <script>
 window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
```