# Why body.addEventListener('scroll') doesn't work while body.onscroll works

Tags: javascript, dom

I've just come across interesting behavior:

```
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', f)
document.body.onscroll = f;
```

When scrolling body, the callback is not triggered in first case and is working fine in the second. Does anyone know the reason for that?

I first assumed that the event is produced on document, however then `body.onscroll` should not be triggered.

[Here is](https://plnkr.co/edit/yJ8MqVhpBgcMCEQSUwwT?p=preview) the plunker.

Comment: Good morning!:) Can you provide a runnable repro of the problem please?

Comment: @yurzui, easy :), check [this out](https://plnkr.co/edit/yJ8MqVhpBgcMCEQSUwwT?p=preview)

Comment: Have you tried it on empty page without iframes?

Comment: @yurzui, yes, sure, you can paste the contents into `index.html` and run it without iframes

Comment: Very interesting thing http://take.ms/xWvyp

Comment: @yurzui, hm, indeed, thanks for the finding, I'll explore it. Or you and post it as an answer)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10832 `Status:  CLOSED FIXED ` how?

Comment: @yurzui, thanks. So it seems that the event is indeed triggered on `window`  and that's why `addEventListener` on the body doesn't work. The side effect of the `onscroll` is that it for some unknown reason registers the even on the window as you showed. That's a great finding. Thanks! Definitely make it an answer

Comment: Now look at https://plnkr.co/edit/igEQ5JyNHjZYDfebH2G2?p=preview :)

Comment: @yurzui, yeah, that's because `window` is not scrolling, the body is)

Answer (score 7):

Discussed here: [Scroll listener on body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951121/scroll-listener-on-body)

You could do it another way:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", f);
```

Comment: it doesn't answer my question

Comment: I found the same behavior with onfocus and onblur. I think it's in attempt to maintain compatibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67940593#answer-67940594