# Why does body.onfocus trigger but not body.addEventListener('focus')?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onblur, onfocus, document-body

Why is it that the `<body>` element's `focus` and `blur` events only trigger via the `.on<...>` property methods and not via callbacks added with `addEventListener`?

The following simple example can be copied and run in the console:

```
const method = name => () => console.log(name);

document.body.addEventListener('blur', method('listener blur'));
document.body.addEventListener('focus', method('listener focus'));
document.body.onfocus = method('onfocus');
document.body.onblur = method('onblur');
```

Switching to a different tab causes the body to *blur*, and switching back to *focus*.
But only `onfocus` and `onblur` log for me, and never `listener focus` or `listener blur`.

This is the case in both modern Chrome and Firefox; thus I presume there's a reason?

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR:

Use `window.addEventListener` or `document.addEventListener`, but *never `document.body.addEventListener`.

#### The issue

The issue is, the `<body>` doesn't have the `focus` or `blur` events; the `document` does. Probably for compatibility with very old sites, however, the `<body>` element allows `onfocus` and `onblur` to be triggered when a focus / blur occurs on the document.

Thus, using `window.addEventListener` should work in most cases since the event bubbles from the `document` to the `window`. And since all other events also bubble from the body, it's probably best to just use `window.addEventListener` for other events too *(*unless there is a specific reason not to, such as when propagation is stopped)*.

This issue is also [apparently the case for the scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632111/why-body-addeventlistenerscroll-doesnt-work-while-body-onscroll-works), since the `<html>` tag is probably what actually *scrolls*. Again, using `window.addEventListener` would catch it when it bubbled.