# Difference between onevent and addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was learning about a few DOM events, and I tried to use the 'blur' event on the HTML body.

**First with onblur**

```
document.body.onblur = () => {
    dosomething();
}
```

and **with AddEventListener**

```
document.body.addEventListener("blur", ()=>{
    dosomething();
})
```

However, only using **onblur** works, so why didn't it work with **addEventListener("blur")** in this case?
Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly it seems to have different behaviour depending on the type of element it is put on.

I think the problem here is what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67940594/6242828):

> The issue is, the body doesn't have the focus or blur events; the document does. Probably for compatibility with very old sites, however, the body element allows onfocus and onblur to be triggered when a focus / blur occurs on the document.

**Update:**

As Yogi pointed out in the comments, according to the [HTML 5 Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#global-attributes:the-body-element) the body element exposes event handlers of the *window* element for some events (including onblur). I.e. body.onblur is just an alias for window.onblur.

**Here's an example of what happens on different elements:**

```js
const body = document.body;
const div = document.getElementById("my-div");
const input = document.getElementById("my-input");

window.onblur = () => {console.log("onblur window");} // triggers if body.onblur is commented out
window.addEventListener("blur", () => {console.log("eventlistener window");}); // triggers

body.onblur = () => {console.log("onblur body");} // triggers
body.addEventListener("blur", () => {console.log("eventlistener body");}); // does not trigger

div.onblur = () => {console.log("onblur div");} // does not trigger
div.addEventListener("blur", () => {console.log("eventlistener div");}); // does not trigger

input.onblur = () => {console.log("onblur input");} // triggers
input.addEventListener("blur", () => {console.log("eventlistener input");}); // triggers
```

```css
#my-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>
<input type="text" id="my-input" />
```

Note that window.onblur is triggered if body.onblur isn't called afterwards